# MongoDB 3.4 Multiple Find Operations

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to execute multiple queries (find operations) in a single network request to mongo servers? Similar to ElasticSearch (msearch).

Thank you!

Comment: out of curiosity, what's the usecase?

Comment: Reducing network traffic between app servers and mangodb servers

Comment: Please read https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/ mongo uses binary protocol with **bytes** of overhead. You will lose more sending a complex query than save on extra request.

Comment: thx. so i guess the answer is no?

Comment: Partially. A query is limited to a single collection, apart from $lookup in aggregation requests. With $facet you can apply different filters to the collection. But it hardly worth efforts if you aim to reduce traffic.

Comment: Why do not you make your comment as an answer so I can flag it as such?

Comment: Because the question is too broad to make a sensible answer. I was curious if there is a real usecase for bulk read, as at the moment bulk operations are limited to inserts and updates.

Answer (score 0):

This is a vague question, but I came across something similar before.

In short there is a situation where it would be nice to query a collection for a list of values and return a boolean as to wether or not that value can be found in a certain key.

e.g.

```
{'Name': 'Bob', 'Age': 32}
{'Name': 'Angie', 'Age': 27}
{'Name': 'Billy', 'Age': 12}
```

Desired behavior in PyMongo:

```
names = ['Bob', 'James']
finds = [Find({'Name': name}) for name in names]
db.coll.bulk_find(finds)
[True, False]
```

Real world example:

I had a database that contained data collected from different sources. As new data came in, sometimes that data was a duplicate and therefore unnecessary. To avoid the overhead of collecting, cleaning, and updating existing data we decided to iterate over the sources and check if each source existed in the collection. If it did not it was appended to a list which would then be used in the collection, cleaning, updating phase.

Obviously as sources grow the number of calls to `collection.find()` do as well. This was a problem, and one that we solve with a `collection.distinct()` call like so.

Original Method:

```
new_sources = []
for source in sources:
    if not db.coll.findOne({'Source': source}):
        new_sources.append(source)
```

Modified Method:

```
existing_sources = set(db.coll.distinct('Source'))
new_sources = set(sources).difference(existing_sources)
```

In the end we got around the desire for a `bulk_read` method by utilizing other collection methods that allowed us to reduce the number of queries required. I have yet to run into another situation in which I thought a bulk read would solve my problem.